# Label text binding with call function and no return value

Tags: google-apps-script, binding, google-app-maker

I have an issue with modifying a label text by calling a function (client script) that call a function (server side) with a return value.

A console.info(return value) show the correct value but the label text is empty.
Even if a make a return like this ==> return "Test", it doesn't work.

Here is my functions created for debug purposes :

**ClientScript :**

```
function onSuccess(value) {
  console.info("debug : " + value); // <== this works !
}

function TestFunction(value) {
  // Call server side functions
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).test("any value");

}
```

**ServerScript :**

```
function test(arg) {
    return "This a return value";
}
```

**Binding in label text :**

```
TestFunction("test")
```

Do you have any idea? What am I doing wrong?

Edit : as ask by Chris, here is the link to the export app zip : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LEcEYtv0guC_ELicE9vFrY8AygJeVqWP/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Where is `TestFunction("test")` / Label Text? And can you post the code for it?

Comment: Hi  Chris, the label is on the main panel. Here is the export of the debug app : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LEcEYtv0guC_ELicE9vFrY8AygJeVqWP/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm not wanting to download zip files... could you just copy and past the relevant 'binding in label text' section?

Comment: Here is the code in the Text property of the widget label :TestFunction("test")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to get the value directly from the server script. As how you see, the console log is working because you are passing the value to the client on the **onSuccess** function.

What you need to do is pass the widget to the **TestFunction** and the **onSuccess** function should go inside the test function. Take into consideration the example below:

**ClientScript:**

```
function TestFunction(widget, value) {

  function onSuccess(value) {
    console.info("debug : " + value);
    widget.text = value;
  }

  // Call server side functions
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).test(value);

}
```

**ServerScript:**

```
function test(arg) {
    return arg;
}
```

**Binding in label text:**

```
TestFunction(@widget, "This is what I want")
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: @Morfinisomo, can we just return a value from function instead of widget.text, I tried, and find if it takes few time to return a value, widget get and show that value; but when it takes time to calculate, then only way is to modify widget as you did in client script, but I cannot find document on time limit on calculation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Albert Sorry but I really don't understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: @Morfinisomo, I had a textbox widget, to set its value, I use a client script function to get a value, when that function is simple like: ```function a() { return 123; }```, then widget value shows as 123, but when function load data source and I find no way the return value can show as textbox value, I had to use widget.value to set value as below, tried return value direct but not work.

```
function getNewClientId(widget) {
  app.datasources.Clients.load(function() {
  var ds = app.datasources.Clients;
  ...
  var newId = paramClient + newNb; 
  widget.value = newId; 
  });
}
```

Comment: @Albert I'm still kind of lost with what you need. Anyways, the server script maximum runtime is 30 minutes. The client script has no limit because it runs on the browser.